# Use Spring Transactional with guava eventBus subscriber

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, guava, event-bus

I'm trying to use guava eventBus to dispatch event within spring.
Inside the event handler I need hibernate to fetch some data -lazy fetch- but it is throwing the error

```
.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
```

and the event bus throws the exception

```
GRAVE: Could not dispatch event
```

My code is as follow:

```
@Transactional
@AllowConcurrentEvents
@Subscribe
public void sessionEventReceived(Session session) {
    session.getTeacher();
}
```

for the entity session I have:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID")
protected Teacher teacher;
```

So can I use @Transactional within eventbus subscriber?

**EDIT**

I have a service that posts the event with the object session (entity session), thus maybe the hibernateSession is closed before the subscriber could retrieve the property teacher, how can I handle that?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the whole picture, what are you trying to achieve with your event bus?

Comment: It depends on how you are registering with EventBus - With Spring proxy it get little trickier, also note that guava subscribers doe not bubble up exception so your transaction won't rollback if event handling throws exception

Comment: as suggested by @Mavlarn , you should not mixing the annotations , even thought you are allowed to. The correct way would be that your Event Listener with the `@Subscribe` annotation , will Autowire the TransactionalService , which will have the methods annotated with `@Transactional`. Also from the context you posted , it doesnt really make sense what you want to achieve, you are opening the session , and you are publishing an event with that ?????

Answer (score 2):

To make the @Transactional work, the method marked as `@Transactional` should be called by spring proxy. Spring will do `start/commit/rollback` work. So if you add annotation with `@Subscribe`, maybe it will not work. (Not sure, I should have tested or dig deeper.)

But you can inject a service object in your Subscriber, and call the Transactional function of that service in the handler function.